# Is it possible to rearrange this for c? $\frac{\sin(\pi-a-b-c)}{\sin(a)}=\frac{\sin(c)}{\sin(b)}$

Tags: trigonometry, triangulation

First post...

Is it possible to rearrange this equation for the variable angle c in terms of the variable angles a and b?

$$\frac{\sin(\pi-a-b-c)}{\sin(a)}=\frac{\sin(c)}{\sin(b)}$$

(a and b variables in the range $0 < a,b < \pi$ and c is in the range $0 < c < \frac{\pi}{6}$)

I have arrived at this equation from a triangulation problem. If there is no solution to this equation, I can elaborate on the actual problem I am trying to solve.

Any ideas/solutions are much appreciated!

Comment: sin(pi-a-b-c) = sin(a+b+c) = sin(a+b)cos(c) + sin(c) cos (a+b). Now rearrange the equation and you will tan (c). Take inverse tan then

Comment: Thank you very much kushpf!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that $\sin(\pi-x)=\sin(x)$, which allows us to simplify a bit.  We then have the sum of angles formula, which states that $\sin(x+y)=\sin(x)\cos(y)+\cos(x)\sin(y)$.  This simplifies things down a bit:

$$\sin(\pi-a-b-c)=\sin(a+b+c)=\sin(a+b)\cos(c)+\cos(a+b)\sin(c)$$

Now we divide both sides by $\sin(a)\sin(c)$ to get

$$\sin(a+b)\cot(c)+\cos(a+b)=\frac{\sin(a)}{\sin(b)}$$

Subtract $\cos(a+b)$ from both sides:

$$\sin(a+b)\cot(c)=\frac{\sin(a)}{\sin(b)}-\cos(a+b)$$

And divide by $\sin(a+b)$.

$$\cot(c)=\frac1{\sin(a+b)}\left(\frac{\sin(a)}{\sin(b)}-\cos(a+b)\right)$$

And then take inverse cotangent to find $c$.

Comment: Thank you very much! That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: No problem, though you should be thanking kushpf